# Making a density arugment with respect to the product topology more rigorous

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = (\Bbb R^\Bbb R, \mathcal{T_{\text{prod}}})$.  Let $D = \{f \in X \mid  f(x) \in \Bbb Q \ \forall x \in \Bbb R \text{ and } f(x)=0 \ \text{for all but finitely many }x\}$. Show that $D$ is dense in $X$.

Let $f \in D$, then $f(x) \in \Bbb Q$ for every $x$ and $f(x) =0$ for all but finitely many $x$.

To show density I need to prove that $D \cap B \ne \emptyset$ for any $B$ basic open set.

Now $B = \prod_{x \in \Bbb R} V_x$ where $V_x = \Bbb R$ for all but finitely many $x$.

So $f \in B = \prod_{x \in \Bbb R} V_x \iff f(x) \in V_x$ for all $x$. Because $V_x$ are open sets in $\Bbb R$ for finitely many $x$ and $f(x) \in \Bbb Q$ and rationals are dense in $\Bbb R$ I think that for every $V_x \ne \Bbb R$ and for every $f(x) \ne 0$ I have that $f(x) \in V_x$.

As for the cases where $f(x) = 0$ I can state that the $x$'s that satisfy these are also in $V_x$ as $V_x = \Bbb R$ for all but finitely many $x$.

---

I feel like I'm not being rigorous here enough. Is there a way to make this more rigorous other than the hand waving I'm doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made most of the right observations, but you haven't made it clear that, given the basic open set $B = \prod_{x \in \Bbb R} V_x$, you can find an $f \in D \cap B$. To find such an $f$: for each of the finitely many $x$ such that $V_x \neq \Bbb{R}$, you choose $y_x \in V_x \cap \Bbb{Q}$ (as you may, since $V_x$ is open and $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$) and put $f(x) = y_x$; while for all the $x$ such that $V_x = \Bbb{R}$, you put $f(x) = 0$. This defines an $f$ which is easily seen to belong to $B \cap D$.

Comment: Thanks Rob! This makes it very clear.